# GET does not send data completely to second page

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Question: Why is my name input not processed?

Context: I have two Java Server Pages. On the first site there is a form and the input is submitted to the second site.

This is the code of the first .jsp file:

```html
<body>
    <form name=test site1.jsp method=GET>
        <label for='name'>Article:</label><br>
        <input type='text' id='name' /><br>
        <label for='price'>Price:</label><br>
        <input type='number' name='price' /><br>
        <label for='tax'>Taxes:</label><br>
        <input type='number' name='tax' /><br><br>
        <input type=submit value=Save />
    </form>
</body>
```

The second site processes the data. My problem is the the fields "tax" and "price" are processesed, but the field "name" is not. It gets a "NULL" value.

This is my output on the second page:

[image]

This is the code of the second site:

```html
<p><%=request.getParameter("name")%></p>
<p><%=request.getParameter("price")%></p>
<p><%=request.getParameter("tax")%></p>
```

Comment: i would try to prepend the `action=` to `site1.jsp` within the `<form>` opening tag...and u should also add `name` attribute to the one u are not receiving as `name="name"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happend because you not set name='name' in your html input and you have syntax error in  tag

your form tag must be like this

```html
<form name='test' action='site1.jsp' method='GET'>
```

replace your name input with this

```html
<input type='text' id='name' name='name'/><br>
```